# Как хранить картинку в БД MySQL, Spring Boot

Tags: mysql

Как хранить картинку в БД

Код таблицы

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String imageUrl;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = true)
    private Category category;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;

        return id == product.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lob

Answer (score 0):

попробуй трансформировать картинку в base64 строку, вот так

```
byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"path to image");
string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

Вначале ты получаешь байт-массив, затем второй строкой преобразуешь его в base64 строку. Ее можно хранить в базе данных.

Чтобы получить картинку обратно в виде `System.Drawing.Image`, выполни:

```
var img = Image.FromStream(new 
MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)));
```

Comment: Вопрос про java ответ про C#